# Simple toggle with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple menu toggle button but the toggle function is not doing what is expected.

I want to run the first function when I click the button (hide the sidebar,make the navbar longer and change the icon) and when I click again do the opposite.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menuToggler').toggle(function() {
    $('#sidebar').css('display', 'none');
    $('#top-menu').css('left', '0');
    $('.content-wrapper').css('width', '100%');
    $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-left', '0');
    $('#navbar-icon').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-bars');
  }, function() {
    $('#sidebar').css('display', 'block');
    $('#top-menu').css('left', '224px');
    $('.content-wrapper').css('width', 'calc(100% - 225px)');
    $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-left', '225');
    $('#navbar-icon').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-arrow-left');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav id="top-menu" class="navbar bg-primary-gradient col-lg-12 col-12 p-0 fixed-top navbar-inverse d-flex flex-row" style="left: 224px;">


  <div class="navbar-menu-wrapper d-flex align-items-center">
    <button id="menuToggler" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler hidden-md-down align-self-center mr-3" type="button" data-toggle="minimize" style="display: none;">
            <span id="navbar-icon" class="fa fa-arrow-left">Toggler</span>
        </button>


  </div>
</nav>

<nav class="bg-white sidebar sidebar-fixed sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" style="display: block;">
    <div class="user-info">
        <span class="online"></span>
        <a class="logout" onclick="logout()"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav">
     
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like `The toggle() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8, and removed in version 1.9.` **How do I make a button to toggle between 2 functions?**

Comment: jQuery .toggle(...) is not what you want, but .toggleClass could work very well. Just set up your different styles in CSS using a class and then toggle the class in the elements that need to change

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it.

```js
var isOpen = true;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#menuToggler').click(function () {
       isOpen ? hideMenu() : showMenu();
    });
});


function showMenu() {
    $('#sidebar').css('display', 'block');
    $('#top-menu').css('left', '224px');
    $('.content-wrapper').css('width', 'calc(100% - 225px)');
    $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-left', '225');
    $('#navbar-icon').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-arrow-left');
    isOpen = true;
}

function hideMenu() {
    $('#sidebar').css('display', 'none');
    $('#top-menu').css('left', '0');
    $('.content-wrapper').css('width', '100%');
    $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-left', '0');
    $('#navbar-icon').removeClass().addClass('fa fa-bars');
    isOpen = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.toggle()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8

https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Instead you could create an 'active' class and add an event listener on the `<button>` element and use `.toggleClass()` instead.

https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: This could work, provided all the fields the OP is wanting to effect are children of the element the class is being put on.  Looking at their code, I'm not sure that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a click event to toggle a class on a parent element (I've used the body tag in this example) and control the styles using CSS:

```
$("#menuToggler").on("click", function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}
.top-menu {
  left: 0;
}
.content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.toggled .sidebar {
  display: block;
}
.toggled .top-menu {
  left: 224px;
}
.toggled .content-wrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 225px);
  margin-left: 225px;
}
```